# mirror certain windows across screens

Tags: linux, windows, mac, multiple-monitors, software-rec

on any OS (preferably windows though) is there a program or way to display a window on 2 screens which are in extended desktop mode. Perhaps I can explain better with a scenario.

A teacher is giving a lesson and also has their email/private stuff that the kids arent allowed to see (like info about other pupils), so they have their laptop docked to a projector.

The teacher and laptop are facing the class so the projector screen is behind the teacher.Because some classrooms the laptop dock is on the right side of the projector and in others it's on the left side the mouse in some classrooms when moved from one screen to another goes to the wrong side of the screen. 
When showing a video on youtube to the class the teach has to bend round to see where the mouse is on the projector relative to the video controls. but has to control the mouse without looking at the (small) touchpad. this is worse when they need to type something in and can't look at the keyboard and projector at the same time.

So it would be better if the browser window (or whatever window) was on both the laptop and the projector screens but none of the other windows or taskbar were.

So a combination of mirror and extended desktop, is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check Ultramon.  You can configure mirroring based on applications.  I've been using it for years and I love it.

http://www.realtimesoft.com/ultramon/

Answer (score 1):

Ultramon as described in [ItsPronounced's answer](https://superuser.com/a/166517/1215765) did not work very well for me on Windows 19 because it forces all windows to update themselves, which took ~30 seconds and one time crashed Microsoft PowerPoint.

In the end, I found a better solution in [this answer that uses OBS Studio preview](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/305314). It has a notable performance impact, though, but switching between two windows has a lower lag:

> ### [OBS — Open Broadcaster Software](https://obsproject.com)
>
> 1. In System Preferences → Displays, do **not** use Mirror Displays.
> 2. In OBS, click the + button under Sources and choose Display Capture.
>
>    [image]
> 3. Set ‘Display’ to your normal display.
> 4. Set Crop to your preferred method of cropping, such as Manual or To Window and configure the crop settings below. Click OK.
>
>    [image]
> 5. Use the red handles to resize your Display Capture source appropriately within the black ‘display’ (preview) in the OBS window.
>    This is how/where your display will show on the mirror.
>
>    [image]
> 6. Right-click anywhere in the preview and choose ‘Fullscreen Projector (Preview)’, then select your external display to output to.
>
>    [image]

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.

Answer (score 0):

OS X doesn't have any methods to accomplish this that I know of. @drpcken's resource will probably do what you want, but I can suggest two "right way" methods to circumvent the problems you mentioned without 3rd party software.

- On the teacher console, put a second monitor next to the laptop and extend the desktop. Then, split that monitor's feed to the projector.
- Mirror the main display to the projector. Make sure the projector can be easily muted, and then have the teacher use Spaces or Fast User Switching to keep the private data out of the way whenever the projector is on.